# Are templates + functors/lambdas suboptimal in terms of memory usage?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, functor

For illustrative purposes, let's say I want to implement a generic integer comparing function. I can think of a few approaches for the definition/invocation of the function.

**(A) Function Template + functors**

```
template <class Compare> void compare_int (int a, int b, const std::string& msg, Compare cmp_func) 
{
    if (cmp_func(a, b)) std::cout << "a is " << msg << " b" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "a is not " << msg << " b" << std::endl;
}

struct MyFunctor_LT {
    bool operator() (int a, int b) {
        return a<b;
    }
};
```

And this would be a couple of calls to this function:

```
MyFunctor_LT mflt;
MyFunctor_GT mfgt; //not necessary to show the implementation
compare_int (3, 5, "less than", mflt);
compare_int (3, 5, "greater than", mflt);
```

**(B) Function template + lambdas**

We would call `compare_int` like this:

```
compare_int (3, 5, "less than", [](int a, int b) {return a<b;});
compare_int (3, 5, "greater than", [](int a, int b) {return a>b;});
```

**(C) Function template + std::function**

Same template implementation, invocation:

```
std::function<bool(int,int)> func_lt = [](int a, int b) {return a<b;}; //or a functor/function
std::function<bool(int,int)> func_gt = [](int a, int b) {return a>b;}; 

compare_int (3, 5, "less than", func_lt);
compare_int (3, 5, "greater than", func_gt);
```

**(D) Raw "C-style" pointers**

Implementation:

```
void compare_int (int a, int b, const std::string& msg, bool (*cmp_func) (int a, int b)) 
{
 ...
}

bool lt_func (int a, int b) 
{
    return a<b;
}
```

Invocation:

```
compare_int (10, 5, "less than", lt_func); 
compare_int (10, 5, "greater than", gt_func);
```

With those scenarios laid out, we have in each case:

(A) Two template instances (two different parameters) will be compiled and allocated in memory.

(B) I would say also two template instances would be compiled. Each lambda is a different class. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

(C) Only one template instance would be compiled, since template parameter is always te same: `std::function<bool(int,int)>`.

(D) Obviously we only have one instance.

Needless to day, it doesn't make a difference for such a naive example. But when working with dozens (or hundreds) of templates, and numerous functors, the compilation times and memory usage difference can be substantial.

Can we say that in many circumstances (i.e., when using too many functors with the same signature) `std::function` (or even function pointers) must be preferred over templates+raw functors/lambdas? Wrapping your functor or lambda with `std::function` may be very convenient.

I am aware that `std::function` (function pointer too) introduces an overhead. Is it worth it?

**EDIT.** I did a very simple benchmark using the following macros and a very common standard library function template (std::sort):

```
#define TEST(X) std::function<bool(int,int)>  f##X = [] (int a, int b) {return (a^X)<(b+X);}; \
std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), f##X);

#define TEST2(X) auto f##X = [] (int a, int b) {return (a^X)<(b^X);}; \
std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), f##X);

#define TEST3(X) bool(*f##X)(int, int) = [] (int a, int b) {return (a^X)<(b^X);}; \ 
std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), f##X);
```

Results are the following regarding size of the generated binaries (GCC at -O3):

- Binary with 1 TEST macro instance: 17009
- 1 TEST2 macro instance: 9932
- 1 TEST3 macro instance: 9820
- 50 TEST macro instances: 59918
- 50 TEST2 macro instances: 94682
- 50 TEST3 macro instances: 16857

Even if I showed the numbers, it is a more qualitative than quantitative benchmark. As we were expecting, function templates based on the `std::function` parameter or function pointer scale better (in terms of size), as not so many instances are created. I did not measure runtime memory usage though.

As for the performance results (vector size is 1000000 of elements):

- 50 TEST macro instances: 5.75s
- 50 TEST2 macro instances: 1.54s
- 50 TEST3 macro instances: 3.20s

It is a notable difference, and we must not neglect the overhead introduced by `std::function` (at least if our algorithms consist of millions of iterations).

Comment: If it is stateless, you can convert a lambda to a function pointer. Just use the unary magic.

Comment: Lambdas are syntactic sugar for functors; (A) and (B) are identical and do not require separate analysis.

Comment: @Casey I agree, but I wasn't 100% sure if two different lambdas mean two different template parameters.

Comment: your `+X` is UB on `sort` as it is no longer an ordering.  Try `(a^X)<(b^X)` to get well defined behaviour that is distinct for each `X`.  Also, create `Test3` where you assign it to `bool(*)(int,int)` which stateless lambdas support.

Comment: You are right, I didn't even think of the comparison function. I was just interested in measuring code sizes due to template instantiations. Anyway, I updated the results with the new function. They are roughly the same. I also added the results (TEST3) for a function pointer. I think the conclusion is straightforward. Working on memory constrained systems and passing more than 10-15 distinct functors/lambdas with the same signature to a template? Then use function pointers. But for best performance use always "raw" functors/lambdas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, **lambdas and function objects are likely to be inlined**, especially if the body of the function is not too long. As a consequence, they are likely to be better in terms of speed and memory usage than the `std::function` approach. **The compiler can optimize your code more aggressively if the function can be inlined. Shockingly better.** `std::function` would be my last resort for this reason, among other things.

> But when working with dozens (or hundreds) of templates, and numerous
>   functors, the compilation times and memory usage difference can be
>   substantial.

As for the compilation times, I wouldn't worry too much about it as long as you are using simple templates like the one shown. (If you are doing template metaprogramming, yeah, then you can start worrying.)

Now, the memory usage: By the compiler during compilation or by the generated executable at run time? For the former, same holds as for the compilation time. For the latter: Inlined lamdas and function objects are the winners.

> Can we say that in many circumstances `std::function` (or even
>   function pointers) must be preferred over templates+raw
>   functors/lambdas? I.e. wrapping your functor or lambda with
>   `std::function` may be very convenient.

I am not quite sure how to answer to that one. I cannot define *"many circumstances"*.

However, one thing I can say for sure is that type erasure is a way to avoid / reduce code bloat due to templates, see *Item 44: Factor parameter-independent code out of templates* in [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876). By the way, `std::function` uses type erasure internally. So yes, code bloat is an issue.

> I am aware that std::function (function pointer too) introduces an overhead. Is it worth it?

***"Want speed? Measure." (Howard Hinnant)***

One more thing: **function calls through function pointers can be inlined (even across compilation units!)**. Here is a proof:

```
#include <cstdio>

bool lt_func(int a, int b) 
{
    return a<b;
}

void compare_int(int a, int b, const char* msg, bool (*cmp_func) (int a, int b)) {
    if (cmp_func(a, b)) printf("a is %s b\n", msg);
    else printf("a is not %s b\n", msg);
}

void f() {
  compare_int (10, 5, "less than", lt_func); 
}
```

This is a slightly modified version of your code. I removed all the iostream stuff because it makes the generated assembly cluttered. Here is the assembly of `f()`:

```
.LC1:
    .string "a is not %s b\n"
[...]
.LC2:
    .string "less than"
[...]
f():
.LFB33:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $.LC2, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp __printf_chk
    .cfi_endproc
```

Which means, that gcc 4.7.2 inlined `lt_func` at `-O3`. In fact, **the generated assembly code is optimal.**

I have also checked: I moved the implementation of `lt_func` into a separate source file and enabled link time optimization (`-flto`). GCC still happily inlined the call through the function pointer! It is nontrivial and you need a quality compiler to do that.

---

Just for the record, and that you can actually *feel* the overhead of the `std::function` approach:

This code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

template <class Compare> void compare_int(int a, int b, const char* msg, Compare cmp_func) 
{
    if (cmp_func(a, b)) printf("a is %s b\n", msg);
    else printf("a is not %s b\n", msg);
}

void f() {
  std::function<bool(int,int)> func_lt = [](int a, int b) {return a<b;};
  compare_int (10, 5, "less than", func_lt); 
}
```

yields this assembly at `-O3` (approx. 140 lines):

```
f():
.LFB498:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x3,.LLSDA498
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    movl    $1, %edi
    subq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 96
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, 72(%rsp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    std::_Function_handler<bool (int, int), f()::{lambda(int, int)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, int, int), 24(%rsp)
    movq    std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<f()::{lambda(int, int)#1}>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<f()::{lambda(int, int)#1}> const&, std::_Manager_operation), 16(%rsp)
.LEHB0:
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
.LEHE0:
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    movq    $0, 48(%rsp)
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L14
    movq    24(%rsp), %rdx
    movq    %rax, 48(%rsp)
    movq    %rsp, %rsi
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rdi
    movq    %rdx, 56(%rsp)
    movl    $2, %edx
.LEHB1:
    call    *%rax
.LEHE1:
    cmpq    $0, 48(%rsp)
    je  .L14
    movl    $5, %edx
    movl    $10, %esi
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rdi
.LEHB2:
    call    *56(%rsp)
    testb   %al, %al
    movl    $.LC0, %edx
    jne .L49
    movl    $.LC2, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    __printf_chk
.LEHE2:
.L24:
    movq    48(%rsp), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L23
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
.LEHB3:
    call    *%rax
.LEHE3:
.L23:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L12
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsp, %rsi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
.LEHB4:
    call    *%rax
.LEHE4:
.L12:
    movq    72(%rsp), %rax
    xorq    %fs:40, %rax
    jne .L50
    addq    $80, %rsp
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L49:
    .cfi_restore_state
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.LEHB5:
    call    __printf_chk
    jmp .L24
.L14:
    call    std::__throw_bad_function_call()
.LEHE5:
.L32:
    movq    48(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    testq   %rcx, %rcx
    je  .L20
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    call    *%rcx
.L20:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L29
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsp, %rsi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    call    *%rax
.L29:
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
.LEHB6:
    call    _Unwind_Resume
.LEHE6:
.L50:
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L34:
    movq    48(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    testq   %rcx, %rcx
    je  .L20
    leaq    32(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    call    *%rcx
    jmp .L20
.L31:
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    jmp .L20
.L33:
    movq    16(%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    testq   %rcx, %rcx
    je  .L29
    movl    $3, %edx
    movq    %rsp, %rsi
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    call    *%rcx
    jmp .L29
    .cfi_endproc
```

Which approach would you like to choose when it comes to performance?

Comment: Why are lambdas and functors the winners in terms of run time memory usage? 100 lambdas mean 100 template instances (even if all the functors or lambdas have the same signature). 100 std::function would mean only one template instance (or actually two, std::function template and the template you are using the "wrapped" function with). I am assuming all functors/lambdas/etc have the same signature so only one std::function template instantiation is enough.

Comment: @jbgs Please re-read my answer, especially the paragraph in which I refer to Item 44 of Effective C++. The problem of code bloat due to templates is well-known; see also a slightly outdated, 12 years old discussion [Code Bloat Due to Templates](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/KwBkmpNZl_U). If you have **facts** to support that code bloat is an issue for you (e.g. you checked the assembly code) then type erasure is one way to go. You can achieve that by passing a `std::function` (ca. 140 lines of assembly code) or a function pointer (5 lines of assembly code).

Comment: @jbgs Here is a *really rough* estimate: based on the length of the assembly for the `std::function()` approach: You would have to have (140/5=)28 template instantiations to generate the same amount of assembly code. Of course this is just a crude and quite questionable estimate but still, it shows that `std::function()` is very expensive both in terms of generated code and in execution time. So, even *if* you get the code bloat (if you get it at all), it takes many many template instantiations until `std::function()` becomes preferable. But as I said before, code bloat is a known issue.

Comment: @jbgs OK, I see you did some measurements. Good. And it is in agreement with what I have just written.

Answer (score 8):

If you bind your lambda to a `std::function` then your code will run slower because it will no longer be inlineable, invoking goes through function pointer and creation of the function object possibly requires a heap allocation if the size of the lambda (= size of captured state) exceeds the small buffer limit (which is equal to the size of one or two pointers on GCC IIRC).

If you keep your lambda, e.g. `auto a = []{};`, then it will be as fast as an inlineable function (perhaps even faster because there's no conversion to function pointer when passed as an argument to a function.)

The object code generated by lambda and inlineable function objects will be zero when compiling with optimizations enabled (`-O1` or higher in my tests). Occasionally the compiler may refuse to inline but that normally only happens when trying to inline big function bodies.

You can always look at the generated assembly if you want to be certain.

Comment: This is my intention. In (C) I want only one instance of the template to be compiled. What happens if I use auto? I would say we would have two different template parameters. Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: Each lambda will have unique type and this may increase the build cost a little. But I don't think it will be significant. (Slow builds are usually the result of including too many headers or doing intensive compile time calculations.) Note: this cost only affects the build times, not the runtime speed.

Comment: I agree, but that's what I wanted to compare :) It's not significant for this naive example. But it could be in some scenarios (memory usage of several compilations vs overhead introduced by raw pointers or `std::function`.

Comment: Keep in mind that including `<functional>` and binding a lambda to a `std::function` will also have a compile-time cost.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wonder if it's worth it... It isn't for two parameters, but it should be worth when we are dealing with a template and several lambdas/functors as parameters (in terms of memory usage, but not in terms of performance).

Comment: Do you mean memory usage when compiling your code or when running your program?

Comment: When running. Two instances of a template mean two compiled instances in memory (besides optimizations).

Comment: Small lambda's like `[](T a, T b) { return a < b; }` may even reduce object size because if they are inlined the generated instructions may end up occupying less space than the space required for a function definition and calls to that function. You should only avoid inlining large function bodies.

Comment: Look at [the assembly code of this little program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b3e266c917671f). The only number you see in the output is `11111`, because the compiler deduced that this was the answer. All the other numbers are gone. Also there's no object code generated for the lambdas. There is no overhead.

Comment: I agree that the lambda instructions may be inlined or easily optimized away. But in general, when the lambda is a template parameter, we can say one template instance will be compiled for each lambda. It makes a difference if the templates aren't so small and naive like my example.

Answer (score 2):

I will discuss what happens naively, and common optimizations.

**(A) Function Template + functors**

In this case, there will be one functor whose type and arguments fully describes what happens when you invoke `()`.  There will be one instance of the `template` function per functor passed to it.

While the functor has a minimium size of 1 byte, and must technically be copied, the copy is a no-op (not even the 1 byte of space need be copied: a dumb compiler/low optimization settings may result in it being copied anyhow).

Optimizing the existance of that functor object away is an easy thing for compilers to do: the method is `inline` and has the same symbol name, so this will even happen over multiple compilation units.  Inlining the call is also very easy.

If you had multiple function objects with the same implementation, havine one instance of the functor despite this takes a bit of effort, but some compilers can do it.  Inlining the `template` functions may also be easy.  In your toy example, as the inputs are known at compile time, branches can be evaluated at compile time, dead code eliminated, and everything reduced to a single `std::cout` call.

**(B) Function template + lambdas**

In this case, each lambda is its own type, and each closure instance is an undefined size instance of that lambda (usually 1 byte as it captures nothing).  If an identical lambda is defined and used at different spots, these are different types.  Each call location for the function object is a distinct instantiation of the `template` function.

Removing the existance of the 1 byte closures, assuming they are stateless, is easy.  Inlining them is also easy.  Removing duplicate instances of the `template` function with the same implementation but different signature is harder, but some compilers will do it.  Inlining said functions is no harder than above.  In your toy example, as the inputs are known at compile time, branches can be evaluated at compile time, dead code eliminated, and everything reduced to a single `std::cout` call.

**(C) Function template + std::function**

`std::function` is a type erasure object.  An instance of `std::function` with a given signature has the same type as another.  However, the constructor for `std::function` is `template`d on the type passed in.  In your case, you are passing in a lambda -- so each location where you initialize a `std::function` with a lambda generates a distinct `std::function` constructor, which does unknown code.

A typical implementation of `std::function` will use the `pImpl` pattern to store a pointer to the abstract interface to a helper object that wraps your callable, and knows how to copy/move/call it with the `std::function` signature.  One such callable type is created per type `std::function` is constructed from per `std::function` signature it is constructed to.

One instance of the function will be created, taking a `std::function`.

Some compilers can notice duplicate methods and use the same implementation for both, and maybe pull of a similar trick for (much) of their `virtual` function table (but not all, as dynamic casting requires they be different).  This is less likely to happen than the earlier duplicate function elimination.  The code in the duplicated methods used by the `std::function` helper is probably simpler than other duplicated functions, so that could be cheaper.

While the `template` function can be `inline`d, I am not aware of a C++ compiler that can optimize the existance of a `std::function` away, as they are usually implemented as library solutions consisting of relatively complex and opaque code to the compiler.  So while theoretically it could be evaluated as all information is there, in practice the `std::function` will not be inlined into the `template` function, and no dead code elimination will occur.  Both branches will make it into the resulting binary, together with a pile of `std::function` boilerplate for itself and its helper.

Calling a `std::function` is roughly as expensive as making a `virtual` method call -- or, as a rule of thumb, very roughly as expensive as two function pointer calls.

**(D) Raw "C-style" pointers**

A function is created, its address taken, this address is passed to `compare_int`.  It then dereferences that pointer to find the actual function, and calls it.

Some compilers are good at noticing that the function pointer is created from a literal, then inlining the call here: not all compilers can do this, and no or few compilers can do this in the general case.  If they cannot (because the initialization isn't from a literal, because the interface is in one compilation unit while the implementation is in another) there is a significant cost to following a function pointer to data -- the computer tends to be unable to cache the location it is going to, so there is a pipeline stall.

Note that you can call the raw "C-style" pointers with stateless lambdas, as stateless lambdas implicitly convert to function pointers.  Also note that this example is strictly weaker than the other ones: it does not accept stateful functions.  The version with the same power would be a C-style function that takes both the pair of `int`s and a `void*` state.

Comment: I have just checked: I moved the comparator to a separate source file (cpp file) and only the declaration was available at the call site. GCC happily inlined the call through the function pointer when I enabled link time optimization (`-flto`). But I agree that it is nontrivial and you need a quality compiler to do this. Luckily, we have one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use auto keyword with lambda functions, not std::function. That way you get unique type and no runtime overhead of std::function.

Also, as **dyp** suggests, stateless (that is, no captures) lamba functions can be converted to function pointer.

Comment: Am I not getting an unique type when using `std::function`? Template parameter is the same for both cases.

Comment: If you want to minimize memory usage (one template instance), convert lambda to a function pointer (or use C-style function pointers - there is no difference).

Answer (score 0):

In A, B and C you probably end up with a binary that does not contain a comparator, nor any templates. It will literally inline all of the comparison and probably even remove the non-true branch of the printing - in effect, it'll be "puts" calls for the actual result, without any checks left to do.

In D your compiler can't do that.

So rather, it's more optimal in this example. It's also more flexible - an std::function can hide members being stored, or it just being a plain C function, or it being a complex object. It even allows you to derive the implementation from aspects of the type - if you could do a more efficient comparison for POD types you can implement that and forget about it for the rest.

Think of it this way - A and B are higher abstract implementations that allow you to tell the compiler "This code is probably best implemented for each type separately, so do that for me when I use it". C is one that says "There'll be multiple comparison operators that are complex, but they'll all look like this so only make one implementation of the compare_int function". In D you tell it "Don't bother, just make me these functions. I know best." None is unequivocally better than the rest.

Comment: It is a naive example. I just used it to illustrate the four approaches. Obviously many things can be optimized away.

Comment: You're trying to make a too-broad sweeping statements that is just plain not true. Read the last paragraph in my reply why not.

Comment: I read it. Of course best approach depends on your particular circumstances. But maybe we can come up with some general guidelines.

Comment: Best you can do is, if a flyswatter is enough don't use a tactical nuke. When a function pointer is enough for the variations you need, don't use std::function.

Comment: @dascandy *"In D your compiler can't do that."* Not necessarily. Please check my answer, in this case, gcc happily inlined that function through the function pointer.

Comment: Dascandy, can you find me the compiler that will optimize the `std::function` in C away?

Comment: @ali Typical for D would be that the implementation is not in the same file, making it impossible for the compiler to inline the call. If you put everything in one file the compiler can (and should!) optimize away your entire program other than side-effect-causing functions.

Comment: @Yakk why doesn't GCC? The entirety of all code is available and should contain no more side-effects so it should inline it completely...

Comment: @dascandy *"Typical for D would be that the implementation is not in the same file, making it impossible for the compiler to inline the call."*  I have just checked: if I enable link time optimization, it gcc happily inlined that function even if the implementation was in a separate cpp (source file). So no, your claim is not true, function calls through function pointers can be inlined. It's not trivial and you need a quality compiler to do that but it can be done, there is no technical reason why not.

Comment: @dascandy On the other hand, I would like to see that compiler that can inline a `std::function` call.

Comment: @ali Link-time optimization is exactly what I'm pointing at and is not in the compiler itself. As soon as you have any possible variation in the contents of the function pointer that won't be inlined anymore either; if it's compile-time not visible that it cannot change it might be link-time inlined but not before.

Comment: @dascandy You are the one asserting it happens: I am skeptical of your assertion.  `std::function` implies virtual function tables, types, `new` being called, `delete` being called, all removed: while legal, I suspect, under as-if, only because the behaviour of `std::function` is left unspecified by the standard.  And as it is implemented in a header usually, the compiler does not know this when optimizing.